# Navigate back from Chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

Could you please help me? I navigate from the Details screen to Chrome custom tabs but when I click on the back button I need to press the back button twice to go back to the Details screen. When I click on it only once I see some blank page. There is no such destination/screen in my project.
Could you please have a look?

```
Navhost: 
        composable(
            route = "webview?url={url}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("url") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val url = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(Utils.URL)

            ChromeCustomTab(url = url)
        }

ChromeCustomTab:

@Composable
fun ChromeCustomTab(url: String?) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build()
            val droppedUrl = url?.drop(6)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(droppedUrl)

            try {
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, uri)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]